# Perform Action when Notification is received?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I want to switch the root view in App Delegate based off when the user receives a notification. Right now, what I have works but the timing is off. As soon as I generate the notification and schedule it, the observer triggers its Selector method, changing a Boolean too soon. The Notification is set to fire 20 seconds in the future.

I'm using a singleton called `StatusOverseer` to guide the notifications and view switching. I put this in `init()`:

```
// Notification Observation
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "bankDidApprove", name: "bankApproval", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "bankDidNotApprove", name: "bankNoApproval", object: nil)
```

This is the method in `StatusOverseer` to generate a notification:

```
func generateNotification(isGood: Bool) {
        if !setNotification && userDidFinishApplication {

            let currentTime = NSDate()
            let fireTime = NSDate(timeInterval: 20.0, sinceDate: currentTime)
            var notification = UILocalNotification()

            if isGood {
                notification.alertBody = "Congratulations! You've been approved!"
                notificationWasGood = true

                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("bankApproval", object: nil)
            }
            else {
                notification.alertBody = "Bank Status is available"
                notificationWasGood = false

                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("bankNoApproval", object: nil)
            }

            notification.alertAction = "open"
            notification.fireDate = fireTime
            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

            setNotification = true
            println("Notification Set")
        }
    }
```

The selector methods:

```
func bankDidApprove() {
        println("Banks approved")

        banksDidRespond = true
        notificationWasGood = true
    }

    func bankDidNotApprove() {
        println("Banks no approved")

        banksDidRespond = true
        notificationWasGood = false
    }
```

And I have this in `applicationWillEnterForeground`:

```
var so = StatusOverseer.sharedOverseer

        // Decide whether or not to present the waiting view
        if so.userDidFinishApplication && !StatusOverseer.sharedOverseer.banksDidRespond {
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("submitWaiting") as! UIViewController

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
        }
        else if so.banksDidRespond {
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            if so.notificationWasGood {
                let vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("approved") as! UIViewController
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
            }
            else {
                let vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("notApproved") as! UIViewController
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
            }
        }
        else if so.userDidAcceptTerms {
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LicenseView") as! UIViewController

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
        }
```

So is there a better way I should be doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: So can I not monitor local notifications? I tried putting the observers in my `submitWaiting` view controller (what should appear before the notification) but it didn't observe the notification as the selector method was never called.

Comment: `UILocalNotification` is not related to `NSNotification` objects and isn't used by instances of `NSNotificationCenter`. They're completely separate mechanisms. Consider modifying your observer methods to use delay the behavior using GCD, a delayed perform, or an NSTimer.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense since I'm running `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("bankApproval", object: nil)` and then immediately checking to see if I did just that. Is there any way to delay that line of code until my Notification fires? Or can i tie them somehow?

Comment: Please edit your question to add more detail. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @jlehr At its essence, what I want to do is run a set of code when a specific notification is received.